# Why does my dionea muscipula (venus fly trap) look a bit sick?

Tags: carnivorous-plants, venus-fly-trap

I've done a little bit of research and it says that it's normal that the traps  turn brown after eating, but the plant is way too small to eat something visible to the eye.

Also they don't look very green to me as they were before.

[image: VFT seedling pic]

Comment: Just for clarification: What are we looking at here? I see the plant, the soil and lots of larger, greenish-brownish lumps...?

Comment: that's the perlite

Comment: So either it’s a tiny plant or huge perlite?

Comment: They are seedlings, they're extremely small .

Comment: Does it get sun light? How much?

Comment: it gets a lot of sun, i also have growing lights .
i think i have watered it too much because i saw it needs to have boggy soil.

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question? Did it die? Is it growing again? You can answer your own question if you did.

Answer (score 2):

sadly it just died, i assume i over watered it :

Comment: Hey Newbie...this is where the adage get back up on the horse that just dumped you makes big time sense.  Yes, you over watered it but there was a reason you tried to grow this plant!  There is a little gardener inside of you that wants to grow plants. Grins!!  So serious!! There is absolutely no way that any gardener became a gardener without more mistakes than successes.

Comment: it may have not completely died, but we can't know.  if the bits of what was left were moved to a dryer spot it may start to regrow again.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, too much water.  Too much soil that holds too much water for way too long.  Bummer!

I would get a mature sized plant from a nursery first.  Learn how to feed insects to it...not too much !!  I love where it takes two taps for the plant to FEEL secure that the insect is worth catching.

Always always use potting soil for any plant in a pot, terrarium, planter.  Always.  Cheapest is the bestus.  No fertilizer added and no water holding gimmicks added!  You need to be in charge of fertilizer.

Venus fly traps also rely on photosynthesis for energy.  Did you put rocks or gravel beneath that soil?  That would also account for the 'bog'...

Comment: i haven't tbh,i'm not sure how the Israeli summer will treat the plant.
I had the plant mostly under growing light and not sun. (i only moved it to full direct sun when it started having black leaves)

Comment: Moving it to direct sun is a death sentence.  Plants have an epidermis that thins in the shade and thickens to protect itself from the direct sunlight.  To move a plant from one environment; indoors to out doors in the sun, from a grow room to a greenhouse, from the out of doors back into the indoors takes a process of acclimatization. Venus fly trap likes partial shade, WELL drained soil, humidity and lots of flies.  Grins.  You need to grow something, anything that will be successful.  To be successful one has to READ, go to classes.  I think staying off the internet would be a good thing.